# Dipole Antenna impedance and feed point, what is the effect of long distance to coax connector?

Tags: impedance, coax, dipole

I have a folded dipole being made with a pair of twisted wires where each wire is 1/4 λ long and the dipole is constructed by twisting the centers of the wires so that the twisted pair is solder for about 1/2 inch.
The two pieces of wire are then inserted into a Junction Box: one end of each wire is screwed into  each of two 2 pole terminal strip. The wires are blue and red with the blues connecting the two terminal strips with a 60 mm wire together. The red wires are fed from each terminal strip to the 2 pins (center and shield) of a coax.  The coax is 50 Ω, frequency range is from 7 MHz to 28 MHz ion 6 different bands.

I hope the image can be enlarged otherwise it's useless.

Comment: I think the image did not get transferred.

Comment: You can actually go copy and paste right into the text box on the website.

Comment: Have you tried copying the image and just pasting it into the middle of your body straight into the text box? I often do that just snipping something off the screen with Window snip tool and copying straight from that window.